# Magento 2 REST API get all product details

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I cannot seem to retrieve `description`, `meta_title`, `meta_description` etc. when using the REST API.

I have tried the below API call with no luck:

`https://domain.com/rest/all/V1/products/123456`

```
{
    "id": 41314,
    "sku": "123456",
    "name": "Some product name",
    "attribute_set_id": 10,
    "price": 500,
    "status": 2,
    "visibility": 4,
    "type_id": "simple",
    "created_at": "2017-06-06 01:34:08",
    "updated_at": "2017-06-06 01:34:08",
    "weight": 1,
    "extension_attributes": {
        "website_ids": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4
        ],
        "category_links": [
            {
                "position": 1,
                "category_id": "483"
            },
            {
                "position": 1,
                "category_id": "307"
            },
            {
                "position": 1,
                "category_id": "434"
            },
            {
                "position": 1,
                "category_id": "534"
            }
        ],
        "stock_item": {
            "item_id": 46746,
            "product_id": 41314,
            "stock_id": 1,
            "qty": 0,
            "is_in_stock": false,
            "is_qty_decimal": false,
            "show_default_notification_message": false,
            "use_config_min_qty": true,
            "min_qty": 0,
            "use_config_min_sale_qty": 1,
            "min_sale_qty": 1,
            "use_config_max_sale_qty": true,
            "max_sale_qty": 10000,
            "use_config_backorders": true,
            "backorders": 0,
            "use_config_notify_stock_qty": true,
            "notify_stock_qty": 1,
            "use_config_qty_increments": true,
            "qty_increments": 0,
            "use_config_enable_qty_inc": true,
            "enable_qty_increments": false,
            "use_config_manage_stock": true,
            "manage_stock": true,
            "low_stock_date": "2017-11-23 15:33:03",
            "is_decimal_divided": false,
            "stock_status_changed_auto": 1
        }
    },
    "product_links": [],
    "options": [],
    "media_gallery_entries": [],
    "tier_prices": [],
    "custom_attributes": [
        {
            "attribute_code": "special_price",
            "value": "0.0000"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "special_from_date",
            "value": "2017-06-06 00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "special_to_date",
            "value": "2017-06-07 00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "news_from_date",
            "value": "2017-06-05 00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "news_to_date",
            "value": "2017-06-07 00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "custom_design_from",
            "value": "2017-06-06 00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "custom_design_to",
            "value": "2017-06-08 00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "category_ids",
            "value": [
                "483",
                "307",
                "434",
                "534"
            ]
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "options_container",
            "value": "container2"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "required_options",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "has_options",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "url_key",
            "value": "some-url"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "msrp_display_actual_price_type",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
            "value": "2"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "gift_message_available",
            "value": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You want to show description, meta_description and meta_title @Cudos

Comment: @Learing_Coder Yes, I wan to show description, meta_description and meta_title.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please find the below screen shot for Your Requirement.

[image]

First You need to Override the Core files in Your module di.xml

To display those description, meta_description and meta_title.

Note:Copy whole default core file and add the below part in respective File code.

File Path:app/code/extension_Name/Module_name/Model/Product.php

```
/**
     * Get product name
     *
     * @return string
     * @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->_getData(self::DESCRIPTION);
    }

    /**
     * Get product name
     *
     * @return string
     * @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
     */
    public function getMetaDescription()
    {
        return $this->_getData(self::META_DESCRIPTION);
    }

    /**
     * Get product name
     *
     * @return string
     * @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
     */
    public function getMetaTitle()
    {
        return $this->_getData(self::META_TITLE);
    }

     /**
     * Set product description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::DESCRIPTION, $description);
    }

     /**
     * Set product meta_description
     *
     * @param string $meta_description
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setMetaDescription($meta_description)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::META_DESCRIPTION, $meta_description);
    }

     /**
     * Set product meta_title
     *
     * @param string $meta_title
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setMetaTitle($meta_title)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::META_TITLE, $meta_title);
    }
```

File Path:app/code/extension_Name/Module_name/Api/Data/ProductInterface.php

in the above File just place the below code as per requirement

```
 const DESCRIPTION = 'description';

    const META_DESCRIPTION = 'meta_description';

    const META_TITLE = 'meta_title';

   /**
     * Product description
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getDescription();

    /**
     * Set product description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setDescription($description);

    /**
     * Product description
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getMetaDescription();

    /**
     * Set product meta_description
     *
     * @param string $meta_description
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setMetaDescription($meta_description);

     /**
     * Product description
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getMetaTitle();

    /**
     * Set product meta_title
     *
     * @param string $meta_title
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setMetaTitle($meta_title);
```

Comment: Hello @Cudos is that the solutions u have been requested.

Comment: I think the problem is to core API, not to custom module